# Python, pip not working, but can't install pip

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I've cloned a project and so when trying to install the packages in the scripts, I get the following error when trying to install from pycharm:

```
proposed solution:

Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/Triangulation-Calculator/venv/bin/python'.

Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/179/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 73, in run_pip
    runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 95, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._internal.models.format_control import FormatControl
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/models/format_control.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.packaging.utils import canonicalize_name
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.packaging'
```

[image]

But when I run it from the terminal it successfully installs the package.

```
pip3 install pandas

...

Successfully installed pandas-1.0.1 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2019.3
```

But in pycharm I can't use it:
[image]

I tried updating venv and pip but it won't work.

And I should mention that it is not the original interpreter as the original's version was python 3.6.

Comment: what interpreter you have set in pycharm ?

Comment: also please explain how did you install it from pycharm?

Comment: Is that the entire error message? The _proposed solution:_ part makes it look it was cut off.

Comment: @AMC that's all the proposed solution by pycharm and the Error part is the command output.

Comment: @kederrac will edit now.

Comment: Note that in the example where _you_ run it, you're clearly using `pip3`, whereas pycharm is clearly using `pip`. Those are completely different commands. So you probably want to tell your pycharm to _also_ use `pip3`.

Comment: Don't use the `pip` script directly, use `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip` instead -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: Nice catch @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I'm voting to close this as a typo.